# Is it possible to connect an external source machine to Live Link?

Tags: animation, networking, unreal-4, plugin, motion-capture

I would like to be able to connect multiple external machines to Unreal Engine via Live Link in order to stream solved motion capture from one of the Vicon run-time solvers/retargeter (i.e. Pegasus). In [one of the streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPcGthmrWxw&feature=youtu.be&t=2467), it was mentioned that Vicon provides a client-side plug-in for Unreal that was used in the Siren demo. I decided to test Live Link's capabilities by connecting from a different machine to UE4 from Maya (I assume that the concept is the same regardless of the source program because at the end of the day we are sending solved animation data, right?). It turned out that Live Link in Unreal out-of-the-box only detects the incoming data from the source machine that is on the same computer where Unreal is running. I am curious as to whether it is possible to modify Live Link or build a custom plug-in using Live Link that would enable me to connect from an external machine to the engine over the network.

The whole topic is very new to me, but I am tasked with providing a solution, so any information would be appreciated. Please correct me if I misunderstand the process. If you know where to look for more details regarding the problem, please tell me.